# If$ A $is invertible $n \times n $ matrix, show that $adj A $ is also invertible and that $(adj A)^{-1} = \frac{1}{det(A)}(A) = adj(A^{-1})$

Tags: linear-algebra

Okay so I used the fact that $A^{-1} = \frac{1}{det(A)}(adj A)$

I solved for adj A and I substituted it in the equation they have given us. 
So now I have:

$[(det A)(A^{-1}= \frac{1}{det (A)}(A) = adj[\frac{1}{det(A)}(adj A)]$

I have no idea where to go from here. Also, if I solve this equation does that mean that A is invertible?

Comment: The essential ingredient is the identity $A \operatorname{adj}(A) = \operatorname{det}(A)1_n$. If $A$ is invertible, then $\operatorname{det}(A) \neq 0$, and hence
$$
 \left(\tfrac{1}{\operatorname{det}(A)}A\right)\operatorname{adj}(A) = 1_n.
$$
What does this imply, then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prove it in the following way
$$(adj A)(adj A)^{-1}=A^{-1}
\det(A)(A^{-1}\det(A))^{-1}\\
=A^{-1}\det(A)\det(A)^{-1}A^{-1}=I$$
Hence $adj A$ is invertible. Then the rest is easy....

Answer (score 0):

You said you have : $A^{-1}=\frac{1}{\det A}(adj A)$

Similarly you can see $(A^{-1})^{-1}=\frac{1}{\det A^{-1}}(adj A^{-1})$

But then, $AA^{-1}=A^{-1}A=I$ and $\det(A)\det(A^{-1})=1$

Can  you conclude now?